# Реализация модели MVC на php

Tags: php, mvc

Есть небольшой опыт (ну прямо скажем совсем маленький)) программирования на C#, в данный момент осваиваю php. Если в С# разделение на модель-вью-контроллер было достаточно понятное, то в php не очень понимаю, каким образом это делается. 
Допустим, создан какой-то класс

```
<?php
class user {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $hash;
    private $salt;
    private array[] $tasks;
    private $mode;

    public __construct ( $id, $name, $email, $hash, $salt ) {
        $this->id = $id; 
        $this->name = $name; 
        $this->email = $email; 
        $this->hash = $hash;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->mode = 1;
    }
}
```

?>

каким образом мне можно отделить контроллер, который будет с этим классом производить какие-то действия, от представления?
Было бы интересно услышать мнения людей с практическим опытом, как делаете, + ссылки на книги, где можно про это почитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну в php нет жёсткого разделения на модель вид и контроллер. Все построенно на совести разработчика и уважении к паттерну.

Схематично, есть 3 файла. представление(вид) - модель - котроллер. вид - выводит html и может содержат php вставки. Модель получает(wherever) и передаёт данные в вид, а контроллер это всё связывает.

Для меня более понятного изложения чем как в codeigniter пока не попадалось, сделайте етот туториал и, я надеюсь, всё станет более понятно 
link here:
[CodeIgniter Tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/)

Example

Controller
    <?php
    class News extends CI_Controller {

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

View

```
 <?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все тоже самое как и на C#. разметка html, не стоит смешивать с php.  по краине мере сморится не очень.

простой пример зоопарка

**interface**`

```
interface iViewZoo {
public function viewCorral($corral);
```

}

```
interface iModelZoo {

public function Corral();
```

}

**Model**

```
class Animals
```

{
    public $varietyOfAnimal;
    public $name;
    public $age;

```
function __construct ($varietyOfAnimal,$name,$age)
{
    $this->varietyOfAnimal=$varietyOfAnimal;
    $this->name=$name;
    $this->age=$age;
}
```

}

```
class ModelZoo implements iModelZoo
```

{

```
public function Corral ()
{
   return array(
       new Animals("mouse","Jerry","1"),
       new Animals("cat","Tom","2")
   );
}
```

}

**View**
class ViewZoo implements iViewZoo
{

```
public function viewCorral ($corral)
{
    foreach ($corral as $animal)
    {
        include "corral.php";
    }

}
```

}

**Controller**
`class Controller
{
    private $view;
    private $model;

```
function __construct (iModelZoo $modelZoo,iViewZoo $viewZoo)
{
    $this->view=$viewZoo;
    $this->model=$modelZoo;
}

public function invokeCorral ()
{
   return $this->view->viewCorral($this->model->Corral());
}
```

}
`**Templante**`




    div{ margin: auto; width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 5px solid green;}
    ul {  width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 2px solid red;}
    body {text-align: center;}

## ZooPark

invokeCorral(); ?>

**corral**

- Variety of animal : varietyOfAnimal";  ?>
- Name  : name";  ?>
- Age : age";  ?>

**index**
`spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once  $class . '.php';
});
$model=new ModelZoo();
$view=new ViewZoo();
$cont= new Controller($model,$view);
include "zoo.php";`

Comment: класс corral есть вставки php кода. echo $animal-> varietyOfAnima; echo $animal-> name; echo $animal-> age;